# How to write custom applications for Kindle 3G?

Tags: kindle

Just wondering whether it's possible to write custom applications for Kindle 3G ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kindle SDK Language/Platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115477/kindle-sdk-language-platform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just googled "Kindle development" and found the [Kindle Development Kit](http://kdk.amazon.com) so it would appear so...