# What language is needed to write applets for e-ink Kindles?

Tags: kindle, kindle-kdk

So I want to write a small app for my e-ink Kindle. I know it's possible -- Amazon has released a [Kindle Developer's Kit](http://kdk.amazon.com/gp/public/gateway), but I can't figure out how to signup (I followed a signup link on another SO post that redirected to the useless homepage).

I've also seen people doing it on the [MobileRead Forums](http://www.mobileread.com/).

The app I want to make is pretty simple, but I can't figure out what language it would need to be in.

What languages are native to the older Kindles (not Kindle Fire)?

Comment: Please see this link for additional information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115477/kindle-sdk-language-platform?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's written in Java, specifically Java 1.4.2.

Comment: So (to oversimplify) I could just upload my own .jars?

Comment: If you can get them signed with the correct keys to authenticate with the Kindle, then yes, but I think it's not quite that trivial. :)

Comment: What else would it entail? Would it be easier if I jailbroke the Kindle?

Comment: @evamvid: You will need to jailbreak it to store your own signing key on the kindel.

Answer (score 1):

Personal Basis Profile 1.1 and Java 1.4

It seams you cannot register as a developer for the old Kindle anymore, so you need to jailbreak it and use a key (that you create yourself) to sign your jars.

You can find instructions what to do and several resources at the URL mentioned below.

There is also a tool to create your own Kindle developer key.

You need to install the public key on your Kindle. To be able to use your jars that you sign with it.

A Hello-World example is also included on the website.

It is also explained how to use [retroweaver](http://retroweaver.sourceforge.net/) that makes it possible to use java 1.5 and than convert it to 1.4.

http://cowlark.com/kindle/getting-started.html

---

*P.s.

Please add a comment as soon as you successfully wrote your first app that runs on your kindle.*